# Two linked spinners not saving as shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner, android-spinner

I am able to save one spinner as shared preferences using [Spinner not saving as Shared/Saved Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663744/spinner-not-saving-as-shared-saved-preference/35664316#35664316).

However I need multiple spinners to be interlinked and I am having issues when i try to save them and I am not sure why.

Here is how my spinners are linked. The first Spinner enables second spinner when it is selected.

```
   spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnMondayExercise); 
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Exercise, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            long item = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            if (item == 0){
                monExc = 0;
                spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnMondayDuration); 
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

And this is the other spinner which becomes enabled by above spinner

```
//Monday Duration
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnMondayDuration); 
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Duration, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            long item = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            if (item == 0){
                monDur = 0;
            }
            else if (item ==1)
            {
                monDur = .16;
            }
            else if (item ==2)
            {
                monDur = .33;
            }
```

Here is my loadData

```
private void loadData() {
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);


    spnMondayDuration.setSelection(prefs.getInt("spnMonDur", 0));
    spnMondayExercise.setSelection(prefs.getInt("spnMonExc", 0));
```

This is where I am saving prefernces:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();

                int spnMonDur1 = spnMondayDuration.getSelectedItemPosition();
                int spnMonExc1 = spnMondayExercise.getSelectedItemPosition();

                editor.putInt("spnMonDur", spnMonDur1);
                editor.putInt("spnMonExc", spnMonExc1);
                 editor.commit();
```

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you want... Can you explain the behavior yo desire, and the behavior you are getting instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code for both spinners is in the same class, than you're completely messing the `spinner` and `adapter` properties. Why not just create two variables for different spinners and two different adapters?

The `onItemSelected()` method of your first spinner is wrong. First you point the variable to the second spinner, set an adapter for it and lastly you disable it - I've really no idea what's your intention behind this. Do you want to reuse the same `Spinner` and populate it with different data (thus different meaning), or you have two separate `Spinner` views?

Assuming you have two different `Spinner`s, I'd do something like this (code is still not clear enough, but use it as a starting point):

```
// initialize Exercise spinner
spinnerExercise = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnMondayExercise);
adapterExercise = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Exercise, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      adapterExercise.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerExercise.setAdapter(adapterExercise);

// initialize Duration spinner
spinnerDuration = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnMondayDuration); 
adapterDuration = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Duration, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapterDuration.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerDuration.setAdapter(adapterDuration);

// disable by default until  an exercise is selected
spinnerDuration.setEnabled(false);


spinnerExercise.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, position, long id) {
        long item = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        if (item == 0){
            monExc = 0;
            spinnerDuration.setEnabled(true);
        }
        ........
    }
}

spinnerDuration.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         long item = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        if (item == 0){
            monDur = 0;
        }
        else if (item ==1)
        {
            monDur = .16;
        }
        else if (item ==2)
        {
            monDur = .33;
        }
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand where I was going wrong now! Thanks for your help :)